# App is rotated to portrait after exiting youtube fullscreen

Tags: ios, youtube, fullscreen, screen-orientation

my app uses an embedded youtube player in `UIWebView` and everything works fine. Except the app's orientation after leaving fullscreen - it's immediately set to portrait. Autorotation is functioning since a user can easily fix it by rotating her device to portrait and back.

It happens on a simulator (6.0, 6.1, 7.0) and device (6.1.3).

For my needs it would be ok to simply remove the ability to enter the fullscreen (button & pinch gesture), but that is not possible, if I'm not mistaken. Experiments with html code resulted in nothing. I'm aware that after fullscreen is left there are `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` calls on the root view controller, but those are not overriden. "Fixing" orientation by setting it programatically is also not possible since iOS 6, right?

This is the html for the embedded player:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type=\"text/css\">
            iframe {position:absolute; top:0px; margin-top:0px;}
            body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?vq=hd720;HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"false\" showinfo=\"0\">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. Removing the code below fixed it:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

From the `UIViewController` documentation:

`If your view controller implements this method, then when presented, its view is shown in the preferred orientation (although it can later be rotated to another supported rotation). If you do not implement this method, the system presents the view controller using the current orientation of the status bar.`

(emphasis mine)